# Why are some users with deriding agenda allowed to raise caste based questions repeatedly?

Tags: discussion

We know that some of the users for obvious reason repeatedly ask caste based question to deride Hinduism under a false disguised name. This seems to be propoganda mission working on Hinduism Stack Exchange, where they are given a free ride. Caste- based questions should be reviewed and approved to verify that it doesn’t fit the agenda of the concerned missionaries.

Example : [Are Shudras allowed to do Adhyayan of (read or recite) Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49861/are-shudras-allowed-to-do-adhyayan-of-read-or-recite-mahabharata)

Now we know of these activities from affiliation with Christianity stack exchange under [this profile](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/53718/john). Here there are conversations with missionaries who learn Indian languages like Telugu, as an attempt to convert innocent Hindus in India as is evidenced from [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123218/discussion-between-john-and-4castle)

Comment: While I don't like Christian missionaries, I think letting them post is good, as it will clear up some misconceptions.

Comment: In any case, the only way the varna system is abusable is if you try and elevate people, instead of putting people down. While many attempts at adding a message of equality to the system have been made, they tend to fail because out of ego people want to be in the higher varnas. If you instead take a human now being a high varna, as so unlikely to not be worth considering, which much more realistic and actually backed by scripture, then you can honestly say the system backs equality for everyone now.

Comment: Said user has far more activity on Hinduism SE than on Christianity. His one question on Christianity is closed (and is weird).

Comment: The user Pasham Vardhan is not a Christian missionary.

Comment: May be because he had asked more caste based questions which are obvious doesn't warrant an answer not only this user I'm asking how to prevent the spam questions on caste